# Diophantine Equations of Degree 2

Tags: diophantine-equations

During my studies, I have seen equations of this form $$xy+bx+cy+d=0$$ Is there a way to find solutions of equations of this form or the number of solutions of equations of this form without factoring or checking within a range?

Comment: That's the same as $(x+c)(y+b)=bc-d$, so really it is just a factoring problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Assuming $b,c,d$ are given integers,

$$(b+y)(c+x)=bc-d$$

Or
$$y=-\dfrac{bx+d}{c+x}=-b+?$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. Could you clarify?